# Memory and CPU usage with different colors in android

Tags: android, memory, cpu, profiler, mobile-development

Do different colors effect the memory usage and CPU of an app ? For eg. A hello world application with red background, will it have more memory usage than a hello world application using black color as the background ?

Comment: No, it won’t affect the memory usage.

Comment: Any Documentation to support this ?

Comment: No, it's just how things work. Colors are colors, they're all the same.